# Stop new windows opening in top left corner?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, window

Is there a registry setting etc for the default window startup location? I'm not talking about individual programs which can save such a setting, but the global default. Windows often opens windows in the top left corner, but with many apps employing a "hover at top of screen" mechanism for making a toolbar swing into view, it becomes desireable for this default window startup location NOT to be jammed up against the top of the screen, so that the new window can be moused over without some other toolbar popping down and obscuring it.

I'm using mainly Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, but probably if there is a setting it's common to other versions too?